# How to identify transcendental numbers?

Tags: field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Given the relationship:

$$\pi = \left(\frac{15ab^2c^3}{2d^4}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

where a, b and c are non-zero positive constants, can it be assumed at least one of a, b or c must be a transcendental number, since $\pi$ is a transcendental number?

After re-arranging we get:

$$\frac{15}{2} = \frac{d^4\pi^5}{ab^2c^3} .$$

Now the expression on the right must be a rational number. Can I assume one (or 3?) of the constants is/are a transcendental number that somehow cancels out $\pi$ being a transcendental number, to produce a rational result?

Can we deduce anything else about the constants? Must at least one be an irrational number? Is it possible to determine which of the constants are transcendental numbers?

Comment: Why use $x*y$ and not $xy$?

Comment: Yes, at least one of them must be transcendental, and that's all we can say. It could be any of them, we don't know which without more information, and the others could be rational. All transcendental numbers are irrational.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan OP asked about the 3 numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ which could be rational if $d$ isn't.

Comment: No, you could have $a=2/15$, $b=c=1$ which are not transcendental (and $d =\pi^{-5/4}$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least one must be transcendental because the products, quotients, and roots of algebraic numbers are also algebraic. Hence if $a,b,c,d$ all satisfied some respective integer polynomials then so would your expression.

But one is all that can be guarunteed. For example, take $a=\frac{2}{15}\pi ^5$ and $b=c=d=1$ as an example where only one variable is transcendental (or irrational for that matter).

Comment: if we re-write the equation as :$$\p^5i = frac{15ab^2c^3}{2d^4}$$ is it conceivable that $\pi^5$ is rational so making it possible that all the constants on the left are algebraic?

Comment: Edit: The re-arranged equation should be: $$ \frac{15 \,a\,\,b^2\,c^3}{2\,d^4} = \, \pi^5 $$ (Could not edit the previous comment as the edit window timed out.)
@Qiaochu

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with transcendental numbers, so I have done a bit more research. As I now understand it, if $\pi^5 $ equated to an algebraic number (let's call it d) then $\pi^5 -\,d = \, 0$ and $\pi$ would be the solution to a polynomial (with algebraic coefficients) and $\pi$ would then by definition not be a transcendental number which we know is not true. By that logic, $\pi^5$ cannot result in an algebraic number. Is that correct?

Comment: @KDP: Yes that's right.

Comment: @KDP It's not "by definition". The definition of an algebraic number is one that is a root of a non-zero polynomial with **rational** coefficients. But there's a theorem that states that if a number is a root of a non-zero polynomial with **algebraic** coefficients the number itself is algebraic.

Comment: @user21820 Not quite. See my comment.

Comment: @jjagmath: It depends on your definition. There's nothing wrong with defining algebraic numbers to be those within the algebraic closure of ℚ within ℂ, which in turn can be defined as the closure of ℚ under roots of non-zero polynomials, which would then include roots of polynomials with algebraic coefficients. Your comment is nevertheless useful.